# i have values i want to execute it in table in SqlDatabase and i use stored procedures , parameters

Tags: c#, sql

when i try this code

```
 public void ExcuteCommand(string stored_procedure, SqlParameter[] param)
    {
        SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
        sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlcmd.CommandText = stored_procedure;
        sqlcmd.Connection = sqlconnection;

        if (param != null)
        {
            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddRange(param);
        }
        sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

to execute it , it give me something went wrong like in this pic  i use for this Datatables and parameters and stored procedure [this is what show when i try to run the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKW4Y.jpg)

Comment: Did you tried to search for error message?

Comment: You can just post the error msg instead of upload a screenshot just to display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your SP you are trying to insert in table ID which has Identity Specification (Autoincrement) property. Remove ID from insert statement and it should work.

Comment: i try to do this but i can't resolve it , can you explain it more , please

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to insert the value of **identity column**(ID).

you can turn off this by appending this to your query statement.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Table_Name OFF
```

Comment: i try it it give me the same result

Comment: Can you show me your query statement?

Comment: try this  SET IDENTITY_INSERT Table_name ON  " your query statement" SET IDENTITY_INSERT Table_Name OFF

Comment: IS this  good for stored procedure ??

Comment: This is not good practice but it solves your problem.By default, it's auto increment.

Comment: Also, please upvote and accept my answer if it solves your problem.